# Use reflection/generics to generate wrapper class

Tags: c#, reflection

I'd like to create a wrapper class dynamically, such that for every desired class (probably underneath a certain namespace like DBO) I'll get an appropriate class like this:

```
public class [ClassName]Wrapper{
    public [ClassName] [ClassName] { get; set; }
}
```

Second, I need to if based on wrapper vs original type. I'm assuming I can just do something like:

```
(classBob as Type).ToString().EndsWith("Wrapper")
```

If I require anything more, please help me out :).

I'm fairly new to reflection and I've never built a class at runtime.  Code to do this would be great, but even pointing out excellent resources to study up on the tools used to do this would be a great move forward for me.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd probably start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What business problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Yeah, I'm there right now. Finding what to build dynamically is the part I'm really lost on.

Comment: The business problem is we're using AutoFixture to generate test class values and due to the project size, generating new test object for every test class is taking far too long.  I want a way to ask in the test method signature for a singleton object that won't be ever be modified across test classes/cases vs a new one that can be modified and tossed.  Only generating a new one when we need to modify within the test will probably save us about 30min in test run time :P.  So I was thinking I could allow for using Document or DocumentThrowaway (or whatever) in the method sig to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't using generics solve your problem?

```
public class Wrapper<T>
    where T : class
{
    public Wrapper(T wrappee)
    {
        Class = wrappee;
    }

    public T Class { get; } // C# 6.0 Syntax, otherwise add "private set;"
}
```

Then you can create a wrapper at runtime with

```
Type typeToBeWrapped = objToBeWrapped.GetType();

Type genericWrapper = typeof(Wrapper<>);
Type constructedWrapper = genericWrapper.MakeGenericType(typeToBeWrapped);
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedWrapper, objToBeWrapped);
```

Comment: Yes, I was expecting to see such a class.  How would I use reflection to instantiate them all using that though?

Comment: @Jonathan This is also easily googleable: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx